# leetcode-540 single element in a sorted array. returning right on local but wrong value on platform

Tags: python, algorithm

Upon submitting the solution for [this problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/single-element-in-a-sorted-array), I'm seeing that while the code passes the test for a really long list which I can't include since it exceeds the character limit with the expected value being 4325 but the returned value being 589.  I was wondering where the bug might be.  The code is as follows:

```
class Solution:
    def singleNonDuplicate(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        if len(nums) == 1:
            return nums[0]
        l = 0
        r = len(nums) - 1
        
        while l <= r:
            m = (l + r) // 2
            lower_len = m - l
            upper_len = r + 1 - m
            if m - 1 >= 0:
                if nums[m - 1] is nums[m]:
                    if lower_len > upper_len:
                        m -= 1
                    else:
                        m += 1
                    lower_len = m - l
                    upper_len = r + 1 -m
                if lower_len == 1:
                    return nums[m - 1]
                if upper_len == 1:
                    return nums[m]
                if lower_len % 2 == 0:
                    l = m
                else:
                    r = m - 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your binary search seems complicated. This would simply pass through:

```
class Solution:
    def singleNonDuplicate(self, nums):
        lo, hi = 0, len(nums) - 1
        while lo < hi:
            mid = lo + (hi - lo) // 2
            if nums[mid] == nums[mid ^ 1]:
                lo = mid + 1
            else:
                hi = mid

        return nums[lo]
```

A bit more interviewy:

```
from typing import List

class Solution:
    def singleNonDuplicate(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        lo = 0
        hi = len(nums) - 1
        while lo < hi:
            mid = lo + (hi - lo) // 2
            if nums[mid] == nums[mid ^ 1]:
                lo = mid + 1
            else:
                hi = mid

        return nums[lo]
```

Or a bit more bitwisey:

```
from typing import List

class Solution:
    def singleNonDuplicate(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        lo = 0
        hi = len(nums) - 1
        while lo < hi:
            mid = lo + ((hi - lo) >> 1)
            if nums[mid] == nums[mid ^ 1]:
                lo = -~mid
            else:
                hi = mid

        return nums[lo]
```

#### Bitwise Operation

You can use both `mid ^ 1` (similar to above solution) or `mid + 1` (similar to below solution), whichever you would be comfortable with. It's fine to use basic bitwise operations for interviews since bitwise relates to algorithms and it would project your fundamental understanding of computer science, especially if you would be a good algorithm developer. But, an opposite view is that to just code as less controversial as possible.

Here is one of LeetCode's solution:

```
class Solution:
    def singleNonDuplicate(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        lo = 0
        hi = len(nums) - 1
        while lo < hi:
            mid = lo + (hi - lo) // 2
            if mid % 2 == 1:
                mid -= 1
            if nums[mid] == nums[mid + 1]:
                lo = mid + 2
            else:
                hi = mid
        return nums[lo]
```

Or:

```
from typing import List

class Solution:
    def singleNonDuplicate(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        lo = 0
        hi = len(nums) - 1
        while lo < hi:
            mid = (hi + lo) // 2
            if mid % 2 == 1:
                mid -= 1
            if nums[mid] == nums[mid + 1]:
                lo = mid + 2
            else:
                hi = mid
        return nums[lo]
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/single-element-in-a-sorted-array/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions, explanations, efficient algorithms with a variety of languages, and time/space complexity analysis in there.

Comment: I was wondering why `mid ^ 1` is used instead of `mid - 1`